# Styling Sheets in Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I will like to change the UIID of the Sheet titlebar and title. I have checked the docs but did not get enough clarity on how to achieve this. How can this be done?

Comment: Are you using CSS or the designer? You need to style Title, TitleArea etc. using CSS/Designer. In the simulator you can use the Component Inspector tool to see the component UIIDs in the hierarchy.